# dynamic highchart config in angular ui grid with angular js using pablojim's highcharts ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angular-ui-grid, highcharts-ng

my code (on the controller) to create an angular ui-grid -

```
function getData() {
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.columnDefs = [];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
         data: 'myData',
         useExternalSorting: true,
         columnDefs: 'columnDefs',
    };
    valuesService.getValues().success(function (data) {
        $scope.columnDefs = getColumnDefs(data.DataColumns);
        $scope.myData = data.Data;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
    }).error(function (error) {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
    });
}

function getColumnDefs(columns) {
   var columnDefs = new Array();
   for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
       columnDefs.push({
          field: columns[i].Name,
          displayName: columns[i].Caption,
          width: columns[i].Width,
          hasChart: columns[i].HasChart,
          cellTemplate: "ui-grid-cell-template.html"
       });
    }

    return columnDefs;
}
```

So in my controller i call the `getData()` function which will populate the grid with the `gridOptions` and create `columnDefs` array

As you see in the `columnDefs` i am using `cellTemplate` in the grid
And this is how my `ui-grid-cell-template.html` looks like -

```
<div ng-if="isChartColumn(col)"> //This works
    <div class="ngCellText column-chart-style">
        <highchart id="chart2" 
        config="{{getColumnChartConfig(col.colIndex())}}"></highchart>   //this does not work
    </div>
</div>
```

So my grid shows data columns and one of the column has a chart, which needs to read the config dynamically from controller's `$scope` object. This dynamic chart config object is to be supplied by `getColumnChartConfig` method on controller's scope which looks something like this in its simplest form -

```
//This function is not getting called
$scope.getColumnChartConfig = function (rowId) {
        return someChartConfigObject;
}
```

Can you please let me know whether this is the correct way to accomplish what i am trying to and if it is then why is the `getColumnChartConfig` method not getting called from my grid's `cellTemplate`? Is there any other approach to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use interpolation `{{}}` directive with config attribute And You inner div function should specifically point to the parent as you used `ng-if`, as it creates new child scope from current running scope. so you need to explicitly point to parent scope using `$parent` keyword

**Markup**

```
<highchart id="chart2" config="$parent.getColumnChartConfig(col.colIndex())">
</highchart>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried this and it is not working. Are you able to give a sample plunkr or jsfiddle? again i appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using appScope as well - refer http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope.

That would make your template more like:

```
<div ng-if="grid.appScope.isChartColumn(col)">
  <div class="ngCellText column-chart-style">
    <highchart id="chart2" config="grid.appScope.getColumnChartConfig(col.colIndex())}}">    
    </highchart>
  </div>
</div>
```