# Load highcharts dynamically with dynamic config option

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am using highcharts.
I am dynamically loading highcharts using ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in chartCheckboxes track by $index">
    <div class="card" id="{{key}}">
            <div class="card-body" id="{{key}}">
                 <highchart id="{{value.chartId}}" config="value.chartConfig"></highchart>
            </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

there is object  of size 20 which loads 20 highcharts on views.

```
$scope.chartCheckboxes = {
 turnover :{
         checked : true,
         title:"Turnover",
         chartId: "chart1",
         chartConfig: "highchartsTurnover"
 },
 operatingProfits :{
         checked : true,
         title:"Operating Profit",
         chartId: "chart2",
         chartConfig: "highchartsOperatingProfit"
 }
//.....like wise another 18 objects
}
```

Problem is config attribute inside highcharts element

```
<highchart id="{{item.chartId}}" config="item.chartConfig"></highchart>
```

not setting dynamically added value, which is set in controller. I have not used interpolation directive {{}} but it is still unable to display.

I took help of this post [dynamic highchart config in angular ui grid with angular js using pablojim's highcharts ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544532/dynamic-highchart-config-in-angular-ui-grid-with-angular-js-using-pablojims-hig)

but cant able to load graph. But, If load it using static values it loads properly.

```
<highchart id="{{item.chartId}}" config="highchartsTurnover"></highchart>
```

Can anyone please help out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are passing only a `string` value of config variable, ideally you should evaluate that variable value aagainst scope & then pass it back to attribute. This can be easily achieve by defining a function.

**Markup**

```
<highchart id="{{item.chartId}}"
  config="getComfig(item.chartConfig)">
</highchart>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.getConfig = function (configName) {
     return $scope[configName];
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks It worked. :)  But, However I didn't understood this line "you should evaluate that variable value against scope". But, It worked as expected and I still wonder by passing value back to function 'getConfig ' and then returning it through scope. I mean what exactly made it to work.